# Distribution Function exact and approximated?

Tags: r

I am doing some exercises in R for statistics and have only one question left that I am not being able to do.

Let *X*<sub>1</sub>, *X*<sub>2</sub>, \dotsc, *X*<sub>*k*</sub> be independent random and identically distibuted variables to X with Poisson distribution of parameter Lambda=8. Using R and fixing a seed in 1284 generate a sample of size 55 of the exact distribution of the random variable S38=∑I to 38 Xi

Based on ggplot2 build a plot of the empirical distribution function associated to that sample. In the same plot present (with different colors):

A. Exact distribution function of S38

B. Approximated distribution function of S38 to Normal distribution

What I have to do is create 38 variables approximated to Poisson(8) distribution and sum to create S38? Also, the exact distribution is the histogram of that created variable? And what about the approximated distribution function of S38 to Normal?

Comment: You apparently have to sample and sum $38$ random variables each $\text{Poisson(8)}$ and add them up, doing this $55$ times, so giving $55$ values, and plot the empirical cumulative distribution function from these values.  On top of that you need to plot a) the theoretical cumulative distribution function for  the sum of $38$ $\text{Poisson(8)}$ random variables and b) the theoretical cumulative distribution function for a normal distribution with the same mean and variance as in (a)

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(1284)
s.38 = replicate(55, sum(rpois(38,8)))
summary(s.38)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  274.0   292.5   304.0   306.3   315.0   371.0 
length(s.38);  var(s.38)
[1] 55
[1] 360.9212

hist(s.38, prob=T, col="skyblue2");  rug(s.38)
 curve(dnorm(x, 304, sqrt(304)), add=T, 
         col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

I am deliberately not using ggplot2, to leave that part to you.
Below is something similar from less-elegant R core graphics.
The plot below shows the empirical CDF (ECDF) of $S_{38}.$

From what discrete distribution is `s.38` a random sample?
You should plot its exact CDF on the same axes.

What normal distribution is @Henry talking about, and why?
I show (red dotted curve) the CDF of a normal distribution.
Whatever it is, it does seem to approximate the ECDF of $S_{38}.$

```
plot(ecdf(s.38))
 curve(pnorm(x, 304, sqrt(304)), add=T, 
        col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

*Note:* For samples with as few as 55 observations, the ECDF of data often seems a better
match to the population CDF, than a histogram of data is to the population PDF. (Some information is lost when data are
binned to make a histogram.)